# How to configure IPN paypal for live transaction in django

Tags: django, paypal-ipn

[image: It's shows error when i do live transactions]

#### It works for sandbox but it's not works for live transaction. I don't have idea how to configure for live transaction.

Please help me I am searching solution for this problem from last 3 days.

```
def process_payment(request):
    domain=request.session.get('domain_name')
    key = request.session.get('key')
    keystore=request.session.get('keystore')
    flag=request.session.get('flag')

    emails=str(request.user)
    strings= key+" "+emails+" "+keystore+" "+str(flag)
    host = request.get_host()
    paypal_dict = {
        'business': settings.PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL,
        'amount': '19.00',
        'item_name': 'Order',
        'invoice': domain,
        'currency_code': 'USD',
        'custom':strings,
        'notify_url': 'http://{}{}'.format(host,reverse('paypal-ipn')),
        'return_url': 'http://{}{}'.format(host, reverse('payment_done')),
        'cancel_return': 'http://{}{}'.format(host,reverse('payment_cancelled')),
    }
    form = PayPalPaymentsForm(initial=paypal_dict)
    return render(request, 'payment/process.html', {'form':form})
```

Comment: Please be more specific about "not works for live transaction."  What, *exactly*, is failing, and with what error? Are the IPNs being delivered in live? What does https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_display-ipns-history show? What is your listener URL's HTTP response? What errors (if any) are logged?

Comment: Please help....

Comment: Well that is a weird screenshot you added, since it has nothing to do with IPN. You are having trouble accepting payments in USD? What is the account's primary currency? You can add a USD balance within the www.paypal.com account interface

Comment: We need credentials key for live transaction. If we need credentials key then where I use credentials key for live transaction.

Comment: I'm sorry, what? What is a "credentials key"? What does this have to do with a discussion about IPN and accepting currencies? Please focus on one problem at a time.